# Split cache data without commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to build a table with the data I have saved in cache, I've split it into: "name=value" and I want a cell with name and a name with value. I've tried to split it again but it does this: "name1" "value1, name2" "value2, name3" etc...

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roucher/d9h6onvr/64/

And the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(document.cookie);
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
var tabla = document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores");
alert (ca);
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i=i+2) {         /* < */
        alert(ca[i]);
        var cas = String(ca).split("=");
        alert("cas "+ cas[i]+ "cas+1 "+ cas[i+1]);
        //alert("i"+cas[i]+"i+1"+cas[i+1]);
        var fila = tabla.insertRow(0);
        fila.id = "fila" + contador;
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        celda1.id = "celda" + contador + "1";
        var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
        celda2.id = "celda" + contador + "2";
        var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
        celda3.id = "celda" + contador + "3";
        celda1.innerHTML = cas[i];
        celda2.innerHTML = cas[i+1];
        celda3.innerHTML = "<button onclick='paseo(" + contador + ")'>'Paseíto'</button>";
    }
});
```

Comment: `java` and `javascript` are two completely different things. . .

Comment: don't `alert` the cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At `var cas = String(ca).split("=");` as you call `var ca = document.cookie.split(';');`, the `ca` has already become an array with format: `['a=b', 'c=d', ....]`, convert it back to string and split by `=` will cause `cas` become `['a', 'bc', 'de', ....]`, so you get something weird. And create another issue later. You should just use `ca[i]`, which is a string like `'a=b'`, and split it again to get `['a', 'b']`, so it could be written as `var cas = ca[i].split("=");`
2. `celda1.innerHTML = cas[i];celda2.innerHTML = cas[i+1];` The `cas` should  now only contain `2` items, the result split by `=`, so use `celda1.innerHTML = cas[0];celda2.innerHTML = cas[1];` instead.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9h6onvr/69/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(document.cookie);
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
console.log(ca);
var tabla = document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores");
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i=i+1) {         /* < */
        // use ca[i] instead of ca.
        var cas = String(ca[i]).split("=");
        alert("cas "+ cas[i]+ "cas+1 "+ cas[i+1]);
        //alert("i"+cas[i]+"i+1"+cas[i+1]);
        var fila = tabla.insertRow(0);
        fila.id = "fila" + contador;
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        celda1.id = "celda" + contador + "1";
        var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
        celda2.id = "celda" + contador + "2";
        var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
        celda3.id = "celda" + contador + "3";

        // Use cas[0] and cas[1]
        celda1.innerHTML = cas[0];
        celda2.innerHTML = cas[1];
        celda3.innerHTML = "<button onclick='paseo(" + contador + ")'>'Paseíto'</button>";
    }
});
```